# elegant way to loop over chunks with remainder in r?

Tags: r

I'm looking for some way to iterate over chunks in R, but right now I'm having to add an additional statement at the end to capture the remainder if the number of items does not divide evenly into chunksize. For example:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(dataframe)/chunksize)){
  (do something with chunk)
}

remainder <- nrow(dataframe) %% chunksize
(do something with dataframe[(length(dataframe)-remainder):length(dataframe),])
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I'm assuming this type of operation is done very often in other code.

Answer (score 9):

If you rly want to keep the `for` construct:

```
chunk_size <- 7
for (i in seq(1, nrow(mtcars), chunk_size)) {

  seq_size <- chunk_size
  if ((i + seq_size) > nrow(mtcars)) seq_size <- nrow(mtcars) - i + 1

  cat(i, seq_size, "\n")

}

1 7 
8 7 
15 7 
22 7 
29 4
```

You can use that to work on the indices you need to.

Here's one w/o the `if`:

```
chunk_size <- 7
chunks <- ggplot2::cut_interval(1:nrow(mtcars), length=chunk_size, labels=FALSE)
for (i in unique(chunks)) {
  print(nrow(mtcars[which(chunks==i),]))
}
```

Comment: wish it didn't have to use an if statement though, but that's a good way, i'll +1

Comment: there's another option w/o the `if`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `split` by taking groups of at least `chuncksize` rows with `cumsum` and `modulo`:

```
n = chuncksize
lst = split(df, cumsum((1:nrow(df)-1)%%n==0))

lapply(lst, function(df_)
{
    #some code on df_
})
```

Example:

```
df = data.frame(col1=letters[1:10])
n = 3  #you want small dataframes of 3 rows

#> split(df, cumsum(1:nrow(df)%%n==0))
#$`1`
#  col1
#1    a
#2    b
#3    c

#$`2`
#  col1
#4    d
#5    e
#6    f

#$`3`
#  col1
#7    g
#8    h
#9    i

#$`4`
#   col1
#10    j
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, if I set `n = 7` and `df = data(iris)`. cumsum(1:150%%7) returns a vector up to 447.

Comment: Doesn't split evenly when it should, try `cumsum(1:10 %% 2 == 0)`. Instead, prolly want something like `(seq(nrow(df))-1) %/% n` with no `cumsum`

Comment: @Frank, yes it's due to the fact the solution with cumsum takes one less element on the first group - but it's not so dramatic since the idea is to roughly divide the data.frame I guess. I agree, your solution is neater but the split has not been explicitely mentionned by the OP ;)